# Модель для друзей социальной сети

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm

Необходимо организовать логику друзей пользователя в социальной сети. Окончательно запутался.

```
public class Friendlist : EntityBase //от EntityBase наследуется Id
{ 
//ссылка на владельца списка друзей
public virtual User FriendOwner { get; set; } 
//список друзей
public virtual ICollection<User> UsersFriends { get; set; } 
} 
public class FriendRequests : EntityBase 
{ 
//ссылка на владельца списка заявок
public virtual User RequestsOwner { get; set; } 
//список заявок
public virtual ICollection<User> UsersRequests { get; set; } 
}
```

`User` будет хранить

```
public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<User> Requests{get; set;}
```

или же просто две ссылки типа? Тут вот совсем не понятно

```
public virtual Friendlist Friends { get; set;}
public virtual FriendRequests Requests{ get; set;}
```

Миграция в таком случае имеет вид, закоменчен код, для случая, если `User` будет хранить ссылки, а не коллекции:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Database.AddTable(
            "FriendLists",
            new Column("Id", DbType.Int64, ColumnProperty.PrimaryKeyWithIdentity),
            new Column("FriendsOwner_Id", DbType.Int64, 30, ColumnProperty.ForeignKey)); 
    Database.AddTable(
            "FriendRequests",
            new Column("Id", DbType.Int64, ColumnProperty.PrimaryKeyWithIdentity),
            new Column("FriendRequestsOwner_Id", DbType.Int64, 30, ColumnProperty.ForeignKey));

     //Database.AddForeignKey("FK_Users_FriendList_Friends", "Users", "Friendlist_Id", "FriendList", "Id");
     //Database.AddForeignKey("FK_Users_FriendRequests_Requests", "Users", "Friendrequests_Id", "FriendRequests", "Id");

    Database.AddForeignKey("FK_FriendList_Users_FriendsOwner", "FriendList", "FriendsOwner_Id", "Users", "Id");
    Database.AddForeignKey("FK_FriendRequests_Users_FriendRequestsOwner", "FriendRequests", "FriendRequestsOwner_Id", "Users", "Id");
}
```